# Compute the maximum resisting torque that can be overcome by the system at the shaft axis

Tags: gears, mechanical

What is the maximum torque the system can withstand at the shaft axis, considering a 2 Nm motor M driving the system through a gear drive and chain drive with an overall reduction ratio between 16:1 and 18:1, and an output speed of 6 rpm?

Comment: i would like to design a gear and chain drives of this system and select the suitable ball bearings for the shaft

Comment: Please add a sketch that describes your mechanism and elaborate about requirements..

Answer (score 0):

As Yaniv Ben David states this post needs some clarification. Add a sketch and some more information.

Assuming "shaft axis" is the output shaft and the transmission goes from fast at motor shaft to slow at output shaft the maximum torque is:

$ T_{out,max} = i \cdot T_{mot,max} = 32 Nm \dots 36 Nm $ for 'typical' electric motors at low speed.

Considering a rough estimate 10% losses in the drive train, this means you get **approx. 29 Nm** of torque on the output shaft.